# Threads vs. GUI in VB

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, user-interface

The language I am talking about is VB.

I'm struggling with this problem for over three weeks, and still a solution is not in sight.
The problem is the following:
I have got an intense calculation running in a sub procedure, while modifying the GUI a lot in the process. After a short period of time, the application freezes and is "not responding". After the calculation is finished, everything suddenly snaps to the point I have modified it. Nothing special about that.
But if I now try to start the sub with a thread, so the application doesn't freeze anymore, I can't access the GUI, because "it isn't created by the thread itself".
How do I get around this??
More concretely: How do I access information about the GUI (especially width and height of a PictureBox) and modify the GUI (especially setting a BackgroundPicture in a PictureBox)?
Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Control.Invoke/BeginInvoke deal with this, E.g. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10311/What-s-up-with-BeginInvoke

Comment: The `BackgroundWorker` class is designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on how to use the `Dispatcher` ([MSDN Threading Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870(v=vs.110).aspx))

> If only one thread can modify the UI, how do background threads interact with the user? A background thread can ask the UI thread to perform an operation on its behalf. It does this by registering a work item with the Dispatcher of the UI thread. The Dispatcher class provides two methods for registering work items: **Invoke** and **BeginInvoke**. Both methods schedule a delegate for execution. *Invoke is a synchronous call* – that is, it doesn’t return until the UI thread actually finishes executing the delegate. *BeginInvoke is asynchronous and returns immediately*.

Small snippit of code from example in msdn article link:

```
startStopButton.Dispatcher
               .BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                            New NextPrimeDelegate(AddressOf CheckNextNumber))
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that out. :)

Comment: It would be good to note that this is the solution for WPF. If the OP is using WinForms he's got to use [**`Control.Invoke()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx).